# Pass data to child component that can be toggled with button click

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-props

I want to pass different data to my slider component on button click. I want to pass 'true ' or 'false' on button click. For this I have used the following code,

```
class DashboardV2 extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: 5,
        edit: false
    }
}
onPress=() => {
  this.setState( { edit: !this.state.edit })}

  render() {
    const title = brand.name + ' - Dashboard v2';
    const description = brand.desc;
  const {data,edit} = this.state; 
    return (
      <div>
        <section>
          <div >
            <h1 style={{textTransform:'uppercase'}}>Communication Skills</h1>
              <p >
                {edit ? 'yes':'no'}
              </p>
              <button onClick={this.onPress}>Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div >
         <Slider1 dataParentToChild1 = {edit} />
         </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DashboardV2);
```

As seen in the code I want to toggle the edit variable in my this.state. With this code the toggling is achieved and rendered on the screen which I can clearly see through `{edit ? 'yes':'no'}` inside the paragraph tags. But this toggling of the edit variable cant be passed through the pros to the Slider1 child `<Slider1 dataParentToChild1 = {edit} />`. Please help me out on this.

My final goal is to pass true or false value to the child component called Slider1 on button click.

This is the Slider1 component code,

```
const sliderProps = {
  width:0,    //dims[0]
  height:0,   //dims[1]
  fill: "none",
  opacity: 0.5,
  stroke: "red"
};

const domain = [0, 10];
const defaultValues = [0, 3];

class Slider1 extends Component {
  onUpdate(vals) {
    console.log(vals);
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: this.props.dataParentToChild1
        
    }
}

  render() {
   //const {data,edit} = this.state;

 console.log(this.state)
    return (
      <div style={{ maxWidth: 600, textAlign: "center" }}>
        <Surface view={view} trbl={trbl}>
          <Slider
            mode={1}
            step={1}
            flatten
            domain={domain}
            component="rect"
            onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
            rootProps={sliderProps}
            values={[0,5]}   //defaultValues
          >
            <Rail>
              {({ getRailProps }) => <SliderRail getRailProps={getRailProps} />}
            </Rail>
            <Ticks>
              {({ ticks, getHandleProps }) => (
                <g transform={`translate(0,${dims[1]})`}>
                  {ticks.map(tick => (
                    <Tick key={tick.id} tick={tick} />
                  ))}
                </g>
              )}
            </Ticks>
            <Tracks left={false} right={false}>
              {({ tracks, getTrackProps }) => (
                <g transform={`translate(0,${dims[1] / 2})`}>
                  {tracks.map(({ id, source, target }) => (
                    <Track
                      key={id}
                      source={source}
                      target={target}
                      getTrackProps={getTrackProps}
                    />
                  ))}
                </g>
              )}
            </Tracks>
            <Handles>
              {({ handles, getHandleProps }) => (
                <g transform={`translate(0,${dims[1] / 2})`}>
                  {handles.map(handle => (
                    <Handle
                      key={handle.id}
                      handle={handle}
                      domain={domain}
                      getHandleProps={getHandleProps}
                    />
                  ))}
                </g>
              )}
            </Handles>
          </Slider>
        </Surface>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider1;
```

Comment: It may help to share the code of the `Slider1` component? Are you saying that the child component does not update when the parent `edit` state value changes?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. I will update the Slider1 code to the question as well

Comment: At the first rendering the value of false can be seen in the console log. But when I click the button the value does not toggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're storing the prop value `dataParentToChild1` in the child component `state`, which is only done in the constructor, and that's only called once. The constructor is not called each time the component is re-rendered (e.g. when a prop value changes).

You also don't need to store the prop in local state like that, in this case. Instead, just use the prop value. So in the slider component, remove the state, and in `render` check with `console.log(this.props.dataParentToChild1)` and you should see the value change each time it's updated in the parent.